# Problem with infopath attachment in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, attachments

I have created Infopath form with attachments. 
When users fill thge form and add files to it. 
I have no possibility to download or view those files.

Is it normal ? thank you,
I have this view :
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to download it? The normal behavior is that when you open Infopath, the attached file name acts as a hyperlink and you should be able to download it by simply clicking on it.

Comment: I open it in browser and try to save it by right click or just  left click on atachment but then it jumps on the top of the page.

Comment: is the behavior consistent in other client machines, browsers?  IP forms and some parts of sp2013 require you to add sp web to compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was configuration problem. I had the view (submitted) that on load is set as read only view. That's why I coulnd't download attachments.